# Installing Windows services gives an error

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, setup-project

I created a simple windows service on my local PC and added the following code to it

```
 Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    Const iTIME_INTERVAL As Integer = 60000      ' 60 seconds.
    Dim oTimer As System.Threading.Timer

    System.IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\AuthorLog.txt", _
        "AuthorLogService has been started at " & Now.ToString())

    Dim tDelegate As Threading.TimerCallback = AddressOf EventAction
    oTimer = New System.Threading.Timer(tDelegate, Me, 0, iTIME_INTERVAL)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()

End Sub


Public Sub EventAction(ByVal sender As Object)
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\AuthorLog.txt", _
        "AuthorLogService fires EventAction at " & Now.ToString())
End Sub
```

Next I added a Setup project to this solution and added a custom action (By double clicking application folder then clicking add output folder then selecting primary output from the dialog). The solution builds fine but I have 2 problems.

1) Everytime I install the service, it asks me for the username, password and confirm password; I was wondering if there was anyway to get rid of it atleast while running locally. I tried setting the account type to user, local service, local system etc but it keeps popping up.

2) Once I enter the credentials (random ones), I get an error "No mapping between account names and security ids was done".

Kindly help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: You could make your service be selfinstalling as in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/WinSvcSelfInstaller.aspx) codeproject article and then just send in the username/password you want to use to the `ServiceProcessInstaller`.

2: Try entering the credentials in a different format. If you're currently using ".\user" try writing "computer\user" or vice versa.

Comment: Installing a service on a server using `installutil.exe`, I actually had to use the `.\user` option instead of the `domain\user` which I thought would be the right option.